# form.$invalid opposite behavior than expected

Tags: angularjs

I want to toggle a form error via a checkbox from controller with:

`$scope.testForm.$error.thisIsAnError = {};`

`delete $scope.testForm.$error.thisIsAnError;`

Unfortunately it behaves completely opposite than expected. If the error is set, the form is valid, if it is not set, the form is invalid.

See [this plunkr for a demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/HNfCggQxvBqexzcLnM66?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you don't have any validating feild inside the form.

Use 'required' it enable angular validating behaviour.

```
  <input type="checkbox" required  ng-model="mainCtrl.errorActive" ng-change="mainCtrl.toggleError()"> Toggle Error
```

Updated plunker:-
http://plnkr.co/edit/HjqGGual68sbR5zwApcd?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

you can add ng-required="true" as follows..

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-required="true" ng-model="mainCtrl.errorActive" ng-change="mainCtrl.toggleError()">
```

this will fix your problem..

updated plunkr-http://plnkr.co/edit/ip9buXX2cU9NHyg3Fq3m?p=preview